# Select Case between number

Tags: vb.net, select-case

I try a select case between number. Each 150000 the code the Textbox5 change on click button.

```
Select Case TextBox5.Text
    Case 0 To 150000
        TextBox6.Text = "-"
    Case 150001 To 300001
        TextBox6.Text = "+1-"
    Case 300002 To 450002
        TextBox6.Text = "+2-"
    Case 450003 To 600003
        TextBox6.Text = "+3-"
    Case 600004 To 750004
        TextBox6.Text = "+4-"
    Case 750005 To 900005
        TextBox6.Text = "+5-"
    Case 900006 To 1050006
        TextBox6.Text = "+6-"
    Case Else
        TextBox6.Text = "+Extra-"
End Select
```

When I try any number between 900006 to 1050006 I have "+Extra-" not "+6-"
and try over 1050006 I have "-"

Comment: Ok... I found Dim range As Integer range = TextBox5.Text

Comment: So, despite receiving 2 equally correct answers you are still going to cast a String to an Integer?

Comment: Turn on Option Strict

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Dim i as Long
If Long.TryParse(TextBox5.Text, i)
  Select Case i
    Case 0 To 150000
      TextBox6.Text = "-"
    Case 150001 To 300001
      TextBox6.Text = "+1-"
   Case 300002 To 450002
      TextBox6.Text = "+2-"
    Case 450003 To 600003
      TextBox6.Text = "+3-"
    Case 600004 To 750004
      TextBox6.Text = "+4-"
    Case 750005 To 900005
      TextBox6.Text = "+5-"
    Case 900006 To 1050006
      TextBox6.Text = "+6-"
    Case Else
      TextBox6.Text = "+Extra-"
  End Select
Else
  TextBox6.Text = "Not a Number"
End If
```

Modify to your requirements.

Comment: @Mike maybe I should rephrase. It's not a ***quality answer***, you have no explanation **or** details as to why the OP code was not working. To back up your answer you should clarify as to ***why*** the code wasn't working, your's does not...

Comment: @Codexer - I gave him the solution, and a much more elegant solution, IMHO. If it is my solution he is using, then my answer should be the one accepted as the solution. Behaviour like this discourages people from answering questions.

Comment: ***Elegant***, how is this elegant? How is the OP supposed to understand their issue if it is not explained? ***You can't fix an issue without an understanding***...

Comment: @Mike I haven't downvoted as I can't be bothered to add insult to injury however look at Tim's answer. It goes into a lot of detail as well as providing a nice solution. That's what Codexer is getting at. Code dumps tend not to be as useful and are often downvoted _even_ if they fix the issue. FWIW upvotes are actually better than accepted answers. Upvotes count towards tag scores which in the long run have better benefits.

Comment: @Mike: imo accepting this discourages people from making the work to suggest improvements, explain the reason why something doesn't work, provide the documentation  and to show alternative approaches.

Answer (score 8):

This is interesting. But before I try to find out what it's causing, I provide you the correct way to do this: a `String` is not a number, set `Option Strict` to `On` and learn to use type safe code. Don't let the compiler guess what you're trying to achieve.

You can use `Int32.TryParse`:

```
Dim number As Int32
If Not Int32.TryParse(TextBox5.Text, number) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer")
    Return
End If

Select Case number ' now integer is the target type
    Case 0 To 150000
        TextBox6.Text = "-"
    Case 150001 To 300001
        TextBox6.Text = "+1-"
    Case 300002 To 450002
        TextBox6.Text = "+2-"
    Case 450003 To 600003
        TextBox6.Text = "+3-"
    Case 600004 To 750004
        TextBox6.Text = "+4-"
    Case 750005 To 900005
        TextBox6.Text = "+5-"
    Case 900006 To 1050006
        TextBox6.Text = "+6-"
    Case Else
        TextBox6.Text = "+Extra-"
End Select
```

This will work and compile also with `Option Strict On`.

Now why your code doesn't work. If you change the last range to `Case 900006 To 999999` it will work as expected. This has to do how strings are compared. Even if this compiles (Strict Off) the `Case` will treat the range `900006 To 1050006` as strings so as `"900006" To "1050006"`, so they are compared letter for letter from left to right, sinvce `"9"` is "greater" than `"1"` this condition is never true, that's why you never get into the last `Case` but into the `Case Else`.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement):

> The expressions in expressionlist can be of any data type, **provided
>   they are implicitly convertible to the type of testexpression** and the
>   appropriate comparison operator is valid for the two types it is being
>   used with.

With `Option Strict Off` the `expressionlist` (the range) is converted to the type of `testexpression` which is `String` (because of `TextBox5.Text`).
With `Option Strict On` you correctly get a compiler error because a `String` is not an `Integer`:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to
>   'String'

Comment: Nice answer and explanation, the case is treating the evaluation as strings (as you mentioned about comparison)... I don't know how many times I have actually seen this bite someone ...

Comment: @Codexer: yes, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) mentions it: _" they are implicitly convertible to the type of testexpression"_ So what you specify first will be the target type for all cases. With `Option Strict Off` the compiler tries to convert the types,**so the integers will be converted to strings not vice-versa**.

Comment: You are correct, as mentioned and as always; great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim Schmelter. Complementing its answer you should use

```
Select Case CLng(TextBox5.Text)
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions for details and while you are at it avoid ids like TextBox5

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this, and it also works if using ASP Classic, which does not support the "To" operator.  This code also shows the use of a nested Select/Case structure, within the first Select/Case:

```
CardName = Left(CardNumber, 4)
Select Case CardName
    Case 1800
        GetCardName = "JCB (Japanese Credit Bureau)"
    Case 2014
        GetCardName = "enRoute"
    Case 2131
        GetCardName = "JCB (Japanese Credit Bureau)"
    Case 2149
        GetCardName = "enRoute"

    'Case 3000 To 3059:
    Case (CardName => 3000 And CardName <= 3059)
        GetCardName = "Diners Club"
    'Case 3400 To 3499
    Case (CardName => 3400 And CardName <= 3499)
        GetCardName = "American Express"
    'Case 3528 To 3589
    Case (CardName => 3528 And CardName <= 3589)
        GetCardName = "JCB (Japanese Credit Bureau)"
    'Case 3600 To 3699
    Case (CardName => 3600 And CardName <= 3699)
        GetCardName = "Diners Club"
    'Case 3700 To 3799
    Case (CardName => 3700 And CardName <= 3799)
        GetCardName = "American Express"
    'Case 3800 To 3889
    Case (CardName => 3800 And CardName <= 3889)
        GetCardName = "Diners Club"
    'Case 3890 To 3899
    Case (CardName => 3890 And CardName <= 3899)
        GetCardName = "carteBlanche"
    'Case 4000 To 4999
    Case (CardName => 4000 And CardName <= 4999)
        GetCardName = "VISA"
    'Case 5100 To 5599
    Case (CardName => 5100 And CardName <= 5599)
        GetCardName = "MasterCard"

    Case 5610
        GetCardName = "Australian BankCard"
    Case 6011
        GetCardName = "Discover"

    Case Else

            Select Case Left(CardNumber, 1)
                Case 1 'Airline
                    GetCardName = "Other (Airline)"
                Case 2 'Airline and other industry assignments
                    GetCardName = "Other (Airline and other idustries)"
                Case 3 'Travel/Entertainment
                    GetCardName = "Other (Travel/Entertainment)"
                Case 4 'Banking and financial
                    GetCardName = "Other (Banking/Financial)"
                Case 5 'Banking and financial
                    GetCardName = "Other (Banking/Financial)"
                Case 6 'Merchandising and banking
                    GetCardName = "Other (Merchandising/Banking)"
                Case 7 'Petroleum
                    GetCardName = "Other (Gas Company)"
                Case 8 'HealthCare/Telecommunications and other
                    GetCardName = "Other (HealthCare/Telecomm/Etc)"
                Case 9 'National assignment
                    GetCardName = "Other [Card Carrier Unknown]"
                Case 0 'ISO/TC 68 and other industry assignments
                    GetCardName = "Other [Card Carrier Unknown]"
        End Select
End Select
```